# Spring Data JPA query returns null

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

> My project based on spring boot,Thymeleaf,mysql,html and Jquery.

i wrote a query for checking user name and password is valid or not,if valid means return TRUE otherwise false..This is my scenario..but it passing null...so it becomes nullpointer exception..
Here is my code

```
public interface RepoUserSignup extends JpaRepository<EntUserSignup, Integer> 
{

    @Query("SELECT pk FROM EntUserSignup pk WHERE pk.username=:uname AND pk.password=:pwd")
    Boolean checkUsername(@Param("uname") String username,@Param("pwd") String password);


}
```

Please help me..Thanks in advance

Comment: what did you mean *but it passing null* ?

Comment: Your query selects `pk`, of type `EntUserSignup`. That's not a boolean. It's a EntUserSignup. And if there is no such EntUserSignup, then the query returns null. That's expected.

Comment: oh..i forgot that..

Comment: Note that this means you're storing passwords in clear text in the database, instead of salting and hashing them. Don't do that.

Comment: i cant understand...what is that mean "salting and hashing" ? @JB

Comment: See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet for example. This is crypto stuff. Hashing applies a one-way, irreversible function to transform the password into something else, salting is done before hashing by appending a random string to the password to prevent dictionary attacks, i.e. hashing common words and compare the result to the stored hash. To verify the password, you use the same salt, then hash the given password, and compare the result to the stored value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query return an Object and not a boolean so you have two ways :

- Your method should return `EntUserSignup checkUsername(@Param("uname") String username,@Param("pwd") String password);` instead then check if there are a result or not
- Another way is to check the number of result `@Query("SELECT COUNT(pk) > 0 FROM EntUserSignup pk WHERE pk.username=:uname AND pk.password=:pwd")` so if there are some results `COUNT(pk) > 0` will return true else it will return false

Comment: hum..Anyother ways to check?

Comment: why you don't want this ways @VigneshR?

Comment: Nothing buddy,just for knowledge... to know the alternative ways...:=)

Answer (score 2):

Replace your method with this:

```
Optional<EntUserSignup> findByUsernameAndPassword(String username, String password);
```

Then in your business layer you can do something like this:

```
EntUserSignup user = findByUsernameAndPassword(username, password)
                     .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found!"));
```

And of cause don't forget about [password in plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47196670/spring-data-jpa-query-returns-null#comment81342367_47196670)...

---

A good tutorial [how to implement security](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/#react-and-spring-data-rest-part-5) in Spring Boot application...

Answer (score 1):

i just change my return type

```
@Query("SELECT pk FROM EntUserSignup pk WHERE pk.username=:uname AND pk.password=:pwd")
    EntUserSignup checkUsername(@Param("uname") String username,@Param("pwd") String password);
```

So when passing username and password matches menans it will return the entity value otherwise null.so we can decide there is no matched username and password.then we can write the logic as

**@Service**

```
public Boolean doCheckUserLogin(EntUserSignup user) {
        Boolean result = false;
        try {
            EntUserSignup entResult = repoSignup.checkUsername(user.getUsername(),user.getPassword());
            if(entResult!=null)
            {
                result = true;
            }
            else
            {
                result = false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

This logics works perfectly...

Comment: The same in one line: `return findByUsernameAndPassword(username, password).isPresent();` ))